# How to plot a matrix with numbers in the matrix colored using ggplot2 or other ways in R? The numbers are the snp count from vcf file

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2, vcf-vcard

I have a matrix like this:

```
Gene      BRCA         THYM         TGHJ
ACC         23          21           7
XTG         12          13           9
CFG         45          4            8
```

I want to plot this in the form of a matrix with numbers colored based on their count; for example the highest number is colored in "Red" and then gradually the intensity of the color decreases with the decrease in number, so in this 45 is colored "Red" and 4 is colored with a very light color. Please let me know if am clear.

I am looking to plot this matrix using ggplot2, but other ways in R are also very welcome. A matrix like this:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947405/ggplot2-heatmap-table-by-row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame( Gene= c("ACC", "XTG", "CFG"), 
                      BRCA= c(23,12,45), 
                      THYM= c(21,13,4), 
                      TGHJ= c(7,9,8))  
mdf <- gather(df, -Gene, key="key", value="count")
ggplot(mdf, aes(x=Gene, y=key, fill=count, label=count))+
      geom_tile()+
      geom_text()+
      scale_fill_gradient(high="red2", low="white")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! thank you so much! Just one query; my data is in a file "file.tsv". Can you please let me know how can I use my file as an input to plot this? Thanks again!

Comment: You can use melt from reshape2 in place of gather.

Comment: You can read your file in like so: `df <- read.table(file = 'file.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks much! I will implement his and let you know how it goes! And, the of corse accept the answer  :)

Comment: Hi, it gives me error "Mapping must be created by aes() or aes_()". Could you please let me know what could be the issue? I have 100 genes to plot. Thanks!

Comment: That's strange, the code works on my machine. Are you using it exactly as in my post?

Comment: This is my code: https://s8.postimg.cc/4kxfgq911/Screen_Shot_2018-08-02_at_4.09.23_PM.png

Comment: Oof, that's a hard format to work with! Remove the text from your call to `geom_tile()`, leaving the parentheses. If you want a title, use `+ ggtitle("I am a title")` Also, the way you use both `scale_fill_gradient` and `scale_colour_gradient` will make the graph unreadable. Remove one (including `fill= ` or `col=` from aes(). )

Comment: Thanks! I did as you suggested; however, I get a plot like this:https://s8.postimg.cc/ffo29t6t1/Screen_Shot_2018-08-02_at_5.10.42_PM.png, and code is this: https://s8.postimg.cc/hk8fb7do5/Screen_Shot_2018-08-02_at_5.13.55_PM.png, I used "melt", but I do not see colors and its not readable. can you please let me know what could be done to make it look better?

Comment: You removed the +geom_tile() part from the code I gave you. Hence, no colors

Comment: Thanks! I added it, now I have this:https://s8.postimg.cc/7x9if2x5x/Screen_Shot_2018-08-02_at_5.35.27_PM.png, can you please letme know how to make the numbers visible in the matrix and the names on x-axis not cluttered? thanks much.

Comment: Change the size on your text will help. Add size=, to geom_text and size= to element_text. The size you export it as will also have an impact (ggsave, height=, width=....)

Comment: Thanks much! I did that and it worked; however, I still cannot see the numbers in the matrix: https://s8.postimg.cc/75bftwdad/Screen_Shot_2018-08-02_at_6.07.53_PM.png, I have done this: https://s8.postimg.cc/htf6s9hz9/Screen_Shot_2018-08-02_at_6.09.40_PM.png

Comment: Put geom_text after geom_tile

Comment: Thanks! I got it:https://s8.postimg.cc/8qqpl9kt1/Screen_Shot_2018-08-02_at_6.34.59_PM.png, now I just want to: put the "title" to center and adjust the size, and increase the size of the legend "value". Please let me know what you think should be done; my code is of the above image is: https://s8.postimg.cc/eroeinkdh/Screen_Shot_2018-08-02_at_6.37.46_PM.png

Comment: Legend size: + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=X)) Title in middle:+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

Comment: Thanks, it works, but for the legend it does not; my code:https://s8.postimg.cc/vagqp54wl/Screen_Shot_2018-08-02_at_6.58.14_PM.png, and the pic is:https://s8.postimg.cc/voi2oh1s5/Screen_Shot_2018-08-02_at_6.59.42_PM.png

Answer (score 1):

As your data seems to be biological, I recommend to use a heatmap function which is also used in several publications.

```
library(gplots)
heatmap.2(as.matrix(df[-1]),
          scale = "none",
          trace = "none", 
          labRow = as.character(df$Gene),
          cexRow=0.9, cexCol = 0.9, 
          cellnote=as.matrix(df[-1]),
          notecol="black",
          notecex = 2)
```

[image]

Try also to scale your data by e.g. `scale = c("none","row", "column")` or different sorting via `dendrogram = c("both","row","column","none")`. You can try to change the color `col= colorpanel(10, low = "white", mid = "yellow", high = "red")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pheatmap` package.

```
library(pheatmap)
```

Example dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(Gene= c("ACC", "XTG", "CFG"), 
              BRCA= c(23,12,45), 
              THYM= c(21,13,4), 
              TGHJ= c(7,9,8))
```

Prepare the data for plotting.

```
rownames(df) <- df[,1]
m <- as.matrix(df[,-1])
```

Plot.

```
pheatmap(m, display_numbers=T, show_colnames=T, cluster_rows=F, cluster_cols=F)
```

[image]